# Increase database size on Adobe Commerce Cloud

Tags: magento2, database, magento2-cloud, magento-cloud

I have enough space in my instance's HD. However, the space allocated to my MySQL database shows **108% usage** by using the command below.

```
magento-cloud db:size
```

How could I increase my MySQL HD's allocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all Starter plan environments and Pro plan Integration environments, you can allocate more space for MySQL in the `.magento/services.yaml` file by increasing the MySQL: disk: parameter. For example:

```
mysql:
    type: mysql:10.0
    disk: 2048
```

> A Starter plan partition should never be made smaller (for example, going from 30GB to 20GB) as this will likely result in catastrophic data corruption.

Reference: [Allocate more space for MySQL in Adobe Commerce on cloud](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/how-to/allocate-more-space-for-mysql-in-magento-commerce-cloud.html?lang=en)